# Adjust static UITableView when keyboard appears?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am working on a app which contains `UITextField` and `UITextView` in static `UITableView`. I am facing two issues

1. When I select `UITextField` it moved correctly but it is not working for `UITextView`.
2. When the keyboard disappears the `UITableView` not shown properly.

All I want is to adjust `UITextField` and `UITextView` accordingly when keyboard appears and disappears. Here is my code.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];




- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
//get the end position keyboard frame
NSDictionary *keyInfo = [notification userInfo];
CGRect keyboardFrame = [[keyInfo objectForKey:@"UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"] CGRectValue];
//convert it to the same view coords as the tableView it might be occluding
keyboardFrame = [self.tableView convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:nil];
//calculate if the rects intersect
CGRect intersect = CGRectIntersection(keyboardFrame, self.tableView.bounds);



if (!CGRectIsNull(intersect)) {
    //yes they do - adjust the insets on tableview to handle it
    //first get the duration of the keyboard appearance animation
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[keyInfo objectForKey:@"UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey"] doubleValue];
    //change the table insets to match - animated to the same duration of the keyboard appearance
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, intersect.size.height, 0);
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, intersect.size.height, 0);
    }];
}


}


- (void) keyboardWillHide:  (NSNotification *) notification{
NSDictionary *keyInfo = [notification userInfo];
NSTimeInterval duration = [[keyInfo objectForKey:@"UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey"] doubleValue];
//clear the table insets - animated to the same duration of the keyboard disappearance
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the UITableView's instance method: **scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:**

In keyBoardWillShow use the tableview's or the textfield's index path and set the scroll position to **UITableViewScrollPositionTop**.

If it doesn't work as you want it to, try with **scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:**

Hope this helps, good luck! :))

For further information, check out Apple's UITableView reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party library for avoiding keyboard scrolling above of text field or text views.
Use https://github.com/cokecoffe/ios-demo/blob/master/TPKeyboardAvoiding/TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.m

**OR**

You can use UITableviewController as your view controller class.Change the Tableview content property to Static. Then you can add any UI controls to the static cells of the table view from story board.
If you select any text field or text view in your tableview, then key board automatically shows below of your text field or text view without any programming logic.